# Was Mozart Bipolar?

Tags: mozart

Was Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart bipolar? After the death of his son, he has written his famous Piano Concerto in A Major which, in the second section demonstrates sad feelings, and in the last section demonstrates fast and happy feelings.

Moreover, in almost all of his works, we can see that abrupt transition from a major key and minor key.

Does this prove he is bipolar? If not, what where the signs and symptoms of a bipolar mentally disturbed person during his time and based on today's standards?

Comment: I think this is off-topic for Music.SE. Maybe it would fit better on [music fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/)? — Regarding “abrupt transition from a major key and minor key”, that is hardly specific to Mozart, lots of classical and romantic composers would do this all the time. I suppose you _could_ ask an objective question here on whether these transitions are indeed over-proportionally employed in Mozart's music.

Comment: This cannot be definitively answered.  This can only serve to exist as a discussion post, which is not allowed in this exchange.

Comment: I think the question, as stated, has a pretty definite answer!

Comment: There are two questions here: 1. was Mozart bipolar? 2. Do the abrupt mood swings in his works prove this? Question 1 is probably not answerable here, or at least a matter of opinion. Question 2 has been (IMHO correctly) answered with "no".

Answer (score 1):

Was Mozart bipolar?  Perhaps.

"Does this prove he is bipolar?" No, not in the slightest.

A composer using dramatic contrasts of happy/sad, major/minor etc.  is definitely NOT evidence of bipolar disorder.  Such contrasts are a common, even a necessary feature of any extended art form.  You can only state a single emotion for just so long!

There is evidence that Mozart had a somewhat juvenile and scatological sense of humour.  Good for him!  This aspect is maybe over-emphasised in certain dramatic depictions of his life.

Comment: "Was Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart bipolar?" is a yes or no question.  Impossible to answer.

Comment: How long do you think, in seconds, must be the pause between the 3 movements in each and every piano concerto of Mozart so it can be "can't be stated in a single emotion for so long"?

Comment: @唐龍豹 perhaps you misconstrue the meaning.  The sentence "you can only state a single emotion for just so long" means that an extended musical work is expected to have contrasting sections with different emotional affect.  A pause between the expression of different emotions is not necessary to the existence of that contrast.

Comment: @Jason P Sallinger But that wasn't the question!

Comment: Laurence Payne, what do you mean?  The question title is "was Mozart bipolar?"; the first sentence is "Was Wolfgang Amadeus Mozart bipolar?"!

Comment: I've even read evidence that Mozart's *entire family* had a similarly scatological sense of humour, including daddy Leopold and sister Nannerl.

Answer (score 1):

> After the death of his son, he has written his famous Piano Concerto in A Major which, in the second section demonstrates sad feelings, and in the last section demonstrates fast and happy feelings.

Contrast is found in all sorts of art forms, including poetry and painting.  It is an integral element in music.  Multi-movement works with contrasting feelings are a fundamental element of European classical music.  They existed for centuries before Mozart was born, probably from the very beginning of multiple-movement works.  You would be hard pressed to find a concerto by Mozart, or indeed by any composer, that expressed a similar emotional affect in each of its movements.  If this contrast implies that the composer is bipolar, then every composer is bipolar.  See, for example, the [doctrine of the affections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_of_the_affections).

The existence of this contrast in this particular piano concerto is therefore not attributable to any event in Mozart's life, though it is certainly conceivable that a significant event could have an impact on the depth of emotion, for example, or on some other aspect of the composition.

> Does this prove he is bipolar?

No.

> If not, what where the signs and symptoms of a bipolar mentally disturbed person during his time and based on today's standards?

This is rather beyond the scope of this site.  If anyone has published anything examining this question, I am unaware of it.  If someone is aware of it, I hope they will post an answer summarizing the findings.  But I would expect the analysis to depend on Mozart's letters and other biographical research rather than on an analysis of his music.